# In Spongebob universe snails are cats. What about bigger felines?

Tags: spongebob-squarepants

I've been rewatching the latest [Spongebob movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_SpongeBob_Movie:_Sponge_Out_of_Water) for the nth time when the scene came where they try to get Gary to join their team. At that moment it struck me - in this cartoon's universe, snails represent cats.

**So what animals are used to represent other, bigger felines?**

I recall there is an episode which takes place in a coliseum where there is a *lionfish*, a big fish with lion's head, but maybe there might be other instances of big cats, I haven't seen all the episodes.

Comment: When a Squirrel represents a texan, I don't think you can expect a logical progression from snail/house cat to something???/big cat.

Comment: @cde :) oh perhaps a large squirrel